# make one field in @RequestBody object have default value

Tags: spring-annotations

I have this rest service method declaration.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/games", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<CreateGameResponse> createGames(@RequestBody 
CreateGameRequest req){}
```

and below is the structure of my CreateGameRequest class -

```
public class CreateGameRequest {
@JsonProperty("noOfStones")
@Value("${noOfStones:6}")
private Integer noOfStones;
@JsonProperty("player1Name")
private String p1Name;
@JsonProperty("player2Name")
private String p2Name;
public Integer getNoOfStones() {
    return noOfStones;
}
public void setNoOfStones(Integer noOfStones) {
    this.noOfStones = noOfStones;
}
public String getP1Name() {
    return p1Name;
}
public void setP1Name(String p1Name) {
    this.p1Name = p1Name;
}
public String getP2Name() {
    return p2Name;
}
public void setP2Name(String p2Name) {
    this.p2Name = p2Name;
}


}
```

I want field 'noOfStones' to be defaulted to value 6 if no value is passed in input. The trick i have used does not work and noOfStones is taken as null if not passed as input. What to do to give it a default value?